# What to use mock parameter or instance parameter in test method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, stub

What is the best practice to pass object parameter in the test method?
What to use in this case?(Mocks, Stubs or create instance of object and fill it)

For example:

```
[Test]
public void LoadContentsFor_ValidUser_ReturnsEmptyList()
{
    var user = new User {Id = 1, FirstName = "Test"};
    var contents = this.contentPresentationService.LoadContentsFor(user);
    Assert.IsTrue(contents.Count == 0);
}
```

Or using mocks:

```
[Test]
public void LoadContentsFor_ValidUser_ReturnsEmptyList()
{
    var user = new Mock<User>();
    user.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(1);
    user.Setup(x => x.FirstName).Returns("Test");
    var contents = this.contentPresentationService.LoadContentsFor(user.Object);
    Assert.IsTrue(contents.Count == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is this simple object I suggest either *creating it by hand* or using some building tool, like **[AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture)** or **[NBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)** (both libraries are designed to deal with the exact issue you are asking about):

```
// AutoFixture example
var fixture = new Fixture();
var user = fixture
    .Build<User>()
    .With(u => u.Id, 1)
    .With(u => u.FirstName, "John")
    .CreateAnynomous();
```

On top of that, AutoFixture offers many more useful features, like

- autogenerating data for properties
- skipping unwanted properties
- replacing certain properties with automocks (give [AutoMoq](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx) a look)

Features, that mocking frameworks don't offer because they server different role. Of course **nothing happens** if you'll still keep using mocks, but given their aforementioned different purpose, it might be *confusing* for readers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

For your case I would create a concrete object of user like in your first example. You do not need to mock it as it exists within the boundary of the code under test.

Any object which exist outside the boundaries of the code being tested and implement data access, services, session management etc should have an interface so that they are not tightly coupled. Having these interfaces allows you to easily mock these areas so no real world data manipulation will take place.